# Change View in Sencha Architect

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch-2, sencha-architect

I am fairly new to Sencha Architect, as well as EXTJs. I have created an application with multiple Views (2 Containers). I am trying to switch views when clicking a button in container1. I have an event created which fires fine, what i don't know is how to switch to the next view? I've tried:

```
if(Ext.getCmp('mainView'))
{
    Ext.Viewport.setActiveItem(Ext.getCmp('mainView'));
}
else 
{
    var view = Ext.create('Snapwire.view.mainView');
    Ext.Viewport.setActiveItem(view);
}
```

But this just throws a console error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object function () {
            return this.constructor.apply(this, arguments);
        } has no method 'setActiveItem'
```

Thanks!

Comment: what contatiner are you using? Also which version of sencha? 1 or 2?

Comment: I'm using a Ext.container.Container, Sencha 2, Architect 2

Comment: are you using card layout? that is what you should be using

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve what you want using navigation view
Please check this link

http://docs.sencha.com/architect/2/#!/guide/navigationview

Hope it Helps ^^

Answer (score 0):

`Ext.getCmp('mainView')` only returns your main view if you set an id for it. In your class definition, add this config:

`id: 'mainView'`

Answer (score 0):

I did this way:

```
Ext.Viewport.remove(Ext.Viewport.getActiveItem(), true);  
Ext.Viewport.add([
 { xtype: 'searchwords' }
 ]);
```

Here,

```
xtype:searchwords
```

is an view called SearchWords where it is defined as

```
alias: 'widget.searchwords'
```

Hope it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using a card layout and change views with:

```
container.setActiveItem(1);
```

or

```
container.setActiveItem(0);
```

(all the containers must be added before you use setActiveItem but it will show only the active item)